# Member since date before 1995

Tags: civimember, search, date-preferences

I'm cleaning up membership data that was imported and need to make changes in the "member since" field. Some people have been members since the 80's. When I try to add pre-1995 dates, I get the following error:

Please enter a date between 01/01/1995 and 12/31/2025

How can I increase the date range so that I can add correct historical membership data?
Thanks, 
Kate

Answer (score 15):

For CiviCRM 4.6+ go to **Administer menu > Customize Data and Screens > Date Preferences**.  From there, change the Start Offset of SearchDate.

For CiviCRM versions before 4.6, this is part of the Advanced Date settings linked from **Administer > Localization > Date Format**.

Comment: Works also for Relationship dates!

Answer (score 2):

Further to Jon's helpful answer, for CiviCRM 4.7.12 (and possibly earlier) the date preference setting that needs to be changed is 'activityDate', as the description makes clear.