# How to enter relationship dates before 1997?

Tags: relationships, 4.6, date-preferences, lts

In relationship management you also want the information to be complete and include relationships that were before CiviCRM was used. This could typically be relationships older than 20 years. CiviCRM imposes a limit and I cannot find the setting to change it to our needs.

Answer (score 6):

For CiviCRM 4.6+ go to Administer menu > Customize Data and Screens > Date Preferences. From there, change the Start Offset of SearchDate.

I found this answer in [Member since date before 1995](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/823/member-since-date-before-1995) and although it talks about Membership dates, it apparently applies to Relationship dates too.